# Java: Getting the subclass from a superclass list

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

i'm new with java and have 2 questions about the following code:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }
class Rat extends Animal { }

class Main {
  List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

  public void main(String[] args) {
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Rat());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Cat());
    animals.add(new Rat());
    animals.add(new Cat());

    List<Animal> cats = getCertainAnimals( /*some parameter specifying that i want only the cat instances*/ );
  }
}
```

1) Is there any way to get either the Dog or Cat instances from the Aminal list?
2) If yes, how should i correctly build the getCertainAnimals method?

Comment: Use instanceof operator http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31.

Comment: use instanceOf()  , to get the type of a class :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Animal a = animals.get(i);   

if  (a instanceof Cat)
{
    Cat c = (Cat) a;
} 
else if (a instanceof Dog)
{
    Dog d = (Dog) a;
}
```

NB: It will compile if you do not use `instanceof`, but it will also allow you to cast `a` to `Cat` or `Dog`, even if the `a` is a `Rat`.  Despite compiling, you will get a `ClassCastException` on runtime.  So, make sure you use `instanceof`.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following

```
    List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    animalList.add(new Dog());
    animalList.add(new Cat());
    for(Animal animal : animalList) {
        if(animal instanceof  Dog) {
            System.out.println("Animal is a Dog");
        }
        else if(animal instanceof  Cat) {;
            System.out.println("Animal is a Cat");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not a known animal." + animal.getClass() + " must extend class Animal");
        }
    }
```

You can also check for the class of the Animal and compare it with Animal sub classes. As in

```
for(Animal animal : animalList) {
    if(animal.getClass().equals(Dog.class)) {
        System.out.println("Animal is a Dog");
    }
    else if(animal.getClass().equals(Cat.class)) {;
        System.out.println("Animal is a Cat");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not a known animal." + animal.getClass() + " must extend class Animal");
    }
}
```

In both cases you will get the outputs as

```
Animal is a Dog
Animal is a Cat
```

Basically both do the same thing. Just to give you better understanding.