# How to use gson to convert json to arraylist if the list contain different class?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I want to store an arraylist to disk, so I use gson to convert it to string

```
    ArrayList<Animal> anim=new ArrayList<Animal>();
    Cat c=new Cat();
    Dog d=new Dog();
    c.parentName="I am animal C";
    c.subNameC="I am cat";
    d.parentName="I am animal D";
    d.subNameD="I am dog";
    anim.add(c);
    anim.add(d);
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(anim);



public class Animal {

    public String parentName;
}

public class Cat extends Animal{
    public String subNameC;
}

public class Dog  extends Animal{
    public String subNameD;
}
```

output string:

```
[{"subNameC":"I am cat","parentName":"I am animal C"},{"subNameD":"I am dog","parentName":"I am animal D"}]
```

Now I want use this string to convert back to arraylist

I know I should use something like:

```
    ArrayList<Animal> anim = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList<Animal>.class);
```

But this is not correct, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: I would suggest make it into a composite class.. but i dont know how to read an array as a class..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you can use the below code to convert json to corresponding list of objects

```
TypeToken<List<Animal>> token = new TypeToken<List<Animal>>() {};
List<Animal> animals = gson.fromJson(data, token.getType());
```

Comment: This works, but I can cast list item to subclass `(Cat)anim.get(0)` in original list while the new list cannot `(Cat)animals.get(0)`, can I save the type for each item to json and restore them to java object?

Comment: I found another problem, now the list is `<ArrayList<ArrayList<Animal>>>`, I tried `TypeToken<List<List<Animal>>> token = new TypeToken<List<List<Animal>>>() {};` and `TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Animal>>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Animal>>>() {};`, both throw exception **class android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView declares multiple JSON fields named mDownPositionY**, how to get object from 2D json?

Comment: for the first problem [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779704/java-getting-the-subclass-from-a-superclass-list) may help you

Comment: Helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @gschambial I'm glad it helped you... :)

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin example:

```
val gson = Gson()
val typeToken = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Animal>>() {}
val list = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<Animal>>(value, typeToken.type)
```

Faster way:

```
val gson = Gson()
val array = gson.fromJson<Array<Animal>>(value, Array<Animal>::class.java)
val arrayList = ArrayList(array.toMutableList())
```